# How to prevent socketIO from emitting duplicate data in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

When I'm emitting `message` from client side.

I'm receiving lot of same duplicated `message`
on server side or in my message displaying container `div` here is the code

**Global Socket Provider Context**

A simple context which provide socket to all children or components

```
// fileName : SocketProvider.js

import { createContext } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("http://localhost:8080/", { withCredentials: true });

const SocketContext = createContext();

export const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket }}>
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SocketContext;
```

And I've wrapped `SocketProvider` in **App.js** like this

```
<SocketProvider>
   <Main/>
</SocketProvider>
```

**In Dashboard Page or Main Page**

Where I've div for displaying messages and input message box whenever user press enter or click send button which is `img` I'm emitting a message here is the code

```
// filename : Main.jsx
// all things imported correctly
import ...

const Main =  ()=> {
   const { socket } = useContext(SocketContext); 
   const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
   const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);
   
   // another global context
   const { currentUserId } = useContext(UserContext);
   const { selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId } = useContext(SelectedUserContext);

   // code for changing selectedUserId
   // ...
    ...
   .... //

   // on start sending userJoined
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("userJoined", {
      senderUserId: currentUserId,
      receiverUserId: selectedUserId,
    });
  }, [socket, currentUserId, selectedUserId]);

 
   // useEffect for listening messages
   useEffect(() => {
    const onMessageReceived = (msg) => {
      setConversation((conversations) => [...conversations, msg]);
    };

    socket.on("message", onMessageReceived);
    return () => {
      socket.off("message", onMessageReceived);
    };
  }, [socket]);

  // this function will send message
  const sendMessage = useCallback(() => {
    if (!message) return;
    socket.emit("message", {
     msg: message,
     sentBy: "Unknown"
    });
    setMessage("");
  }, [socket, message]);

  // on enter btn pressed
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEnterKeyPressed = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey === false && e.ctrlKey === false)
        sendMessage();
    };

    element.addEventListener("keydown", handleEnterKeyPressed);
    return () => {
      element.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEnterKeyPressed);
    };
  }, [sendMessage]);

   return (
     <div className="container">
        <div className="msgContainer">
          {conversation.map((data)=>((
             <h1 className="...">{data.msg}</h1>
             <p className="...">{data.sentBy}</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <input
          value={message}
          onChange={(e)=>setMessage(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Enter message here"/>
        <img className="..." src={sendIcon} onClick={sendMessage}>
     </div>
   );
}
export default Main;
```

**Code In Server Side Where I'm Listening for message**

```
//filename: server.js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("userJoined", (userJoinedData) => {
     const chatRoomId = generateChatRoomId(userJoinedData);
     socket.on("message", async (msgData) => {
      // this console log many times or more than 11 
      console.log(`DEBUG: New Message Arrived :`, msgData);
     
      // saving msg to mongo db
      const savedMessage = await saveMsg(msgData);
      io.to(chatRoomId).emit("message", savedMessage);
    });

  });

});
```

and even I got following warning in terminal :

> (node:14040) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added
> to [Socket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Any help will be always appreciated :)

Comment: In your server code, what dose the code look like that `socket.on("message", async (msgData) => {` sits in? Is that peice of code being executed multiple times?

Comment: @NickParsons thanks for pointing out Now I've updated code you can check

Comment: @NickParsons I also added client side's more code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NickParsons mentioned -

> Is that peice of code being executed multiple times?

Whenever `currentUserId` or `selectedUserId` changes you are emiting `userJoined` in server code. And `userJoined` listener on server side get called and your **message** listener listen again your data so that's why you are getting duplicated data.

To fix this you have to place `message` listener outside of `userJoined` listener!

> I know you are getting some info of `userJoinedData` so that's why you have place `message` listener inside `userJoined`.

So you have to also pass that userJoinedData while emitting message in your client side and change code in your server side like this -

```
//filename: server.js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("userJoined", (userJoinedData) => {
     const chatRoomId = generateChatRoomId(userJoinedData);
     // .. your other codes
  });
  
  // but place message listener outside here

  socket.on("message", async (msgData, userJoinedData) => {
      // now here also you can generate chatRoomId
      const chatRoomId = generateChatRoomId(userJoinedData);

      // saving msg to mongo db
      const savedMessage = await saveMsg(msgData);
      io.to(chatRoomId).emit("message", savedMessage);
    });

});
```